# Nginx Configure Two Angular2's quickstart work well?

Tags: node.js, nginx, angular

#### 1. Get ***Angular2's quickstart***

https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git
***Git clone*** or ***Download*** [Angular2's quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git) Two copies:
quickstart1
quickstart2

#### 2. Start ***Angular2's quickstart***

`start quickstart1:
xxx:xxx xxx$ cd quickstart1
xxx:xxx xxx$ npm install
xxx:xxx xxx$ npm start`

`start quickstart2:
xxx:xxx xxx$ cd quickstart2
xxx:xxx xxx$ npm install
xxx:xxx xxx$ npm start`

We can access two quickstart:
quickstart1:  http://localhost:3000/ (http://127.0.0.1:3000/)
quickstart2:  http://localhost:3002/ (http://127.0.0.1:3002/)

#### 3. Add Image Into quickstart for Root Request(This is optional)

(1) Pick up a image file (different from quickstart2), change name to:
**test.png**
Put it in: **quickstart1**

`qucikstart1/index.html:

    <body>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
        <img src="/test.png" style="width: 240px; height: 240px" />
    </body>`

(2) Pick up a image file (different from quickstart1), change name to:
**test.png**
Put it in: **quickstart2**

`qucikstart2/index.html:

    <body>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
        <img src="/test.png" style="width: 240px; height: 240px" />
    </body>`

#### 4. Wanted

Configure Nginx, Access two quickstart by **one port**, route by **two location path**:
http://xxx_ip_or_servername_xxx:8888/q1/ -> http://localhost:3000/
http://xxx_ip_or_servername_xxx:8888/q2/ -> http://localhost:3002/

"Chrome Developer Tools -> Network" should all right.
And q1 q2 show different img, if you do step 3.

#### 5. Notice

Check "Chrome Developer Tools -> Network"

Access "[http://xxx_ip_or_servername_xxx:8888/**q1**/](http://xxx_ip_or_servername_xxx:8888/__q1__/)"
root request like "/browser-sync" "/favicon.ico" "**/test.png**"
should from "http://localhost:3001/"

Access "[http://xxx_ip_or_servername_xxx:8888/**q2**/](http://xxx_ip_or_servername_xxx:8888/__q2__/)"
root request like "/browser-sync" "/favicon.ico" "**/test.png**"
should from "http://localhost:3002/"

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Can you show your current nginx conf file? All you need is to create two *location* definitions.

Comment: It's not as easy as saying.You should comment it after using hands-on experiment.